# Wordpress SQL Command to delete all posts and the belonging data from a specific author

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I need a SQL Query to `delete all posts` (custom post types) and all the data belonging to those posts from a specific `post author`.

We are talking about more than `20,000` posts so I can’t use the bulk delete function from the WP admin side.

Thanks for help!
Regards

Comment: Post your table definition `SHOW CREATE tableName`

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**, I wouldn't recommend deleting them this way (By running a SQL directly in admin ) as the postmeta  table would have more information about the posts that  will remain in the database. You should rather use the [wp_delete_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post)  function  in a loop. I will show you how in a bit.

**Second of all**: You need to make sure WP is allotted enough memory to process such a loop. The codex info refer to wp-config.php but in recent versions of wordpress, it's in wp-settings.php in the root folder of your installation. http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP Once you have finished deleting the posts, you can reset the limit to what it was before.

**Thirdly**: If you can't run this code in a custom plugin in the back end, you can do so in the  front end. This function will do it:

```
global $wpdb; 
$evil_author = THE_ID_OF_THE_AUTHOR_WHOSE_POSTS_YOU_WANNA_BUZZIATE;
$them_posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE AND post_author = $evil_author" AND post_type = "my_post_type"); // Replace my_post_type  by the post type you want

foreach ( $them_posts as $post_die ) 
{
    wp_delete_post( $post_die->ID, true ); // Bypasses Trash and deletes all the posts


} // ************   BE SUPER CAREFUL BECAUSE THIS IS IRREVERSIBLE. So, BACK UP  **************
```

**NB:** ***Notice that the function also deletes all the comments and any other meta relationship pertaining to that post***.